# Why can't I detect start condition when to bitbang-read/sniff I2C port? stm32

Tags: embedded, stm32, gpio, i2c

I am trying to bitbang-read or rather sniff an I2C port. I have successful I2C communication between a master I2C device and a Nucleo stm32F401 board. Nucleo slave sending using DMA. Then I am using 2 pins from the same Nucleo to try to sniff the communication. Both of the pins are configured as inuputs with pull-ups.

I read the pins' value like this:

```
while (1) {

    uint8_t CLK_val = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, 1);
    uint8_t SDA_val = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, 2);

//And then I try to detect start condition like this:

    if (CLK_val == GPIO_PIN_RESET && SDA_val == GPIO_PIN_RESET){
        //Some code
    }

//More code

};
```

If I manually pull the pins down, touching both of them with a cable connected to ground, the condition is met. But the I2C transaction doesn't trigger the condition even though the transaction is being successful and thus the pins must have been pulled down during the transaction.

Why would the condition not be met during the I2C transaction?

Comment: How long are both pins pulled down during the start condition (i.e. how long is the start bit)?  And then how often does your while loop run and read the status of the pins?  Perhaps the while loop doesn't read the pin status often enough to catch the start bit.

Comment: Looking at some bitbanging examples they all used a delay to make the code run as slow as the I2C protocol so I assumed that the processor should be faster than the protocol. @Tom V's solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AN I2C start condition is a falling edge of data while clock remains high.  To detect it from GPIO you need to do something like:

```
CLK_val_before = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, 1);
SDA_val_before = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, 2);
CLK_val_after = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, 1);
SDA_val_after = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, 2);

if ((CLK_val_before == GPIO_PIN_SET) 
    && (SDA_val_before == GPIO_PIN_SET) 
    && (CLK_val_after == GPIO_PIN_SET) 
    && (SDA_val_after == GPIO_PIN_RESET))
{
    // Some code
}
```

Comment: I based my code on a diagram that didn't show very clearly that the start condition is only data going low. Now working as expected! Thanks!